# Failed during install WWW::Curl::Easy in cpan

Tags: perl, curl

I am installing perl module "WWW::Curl::Easy" but it's getting error I also use by fource install but it's getting same error. why this is happend plz help me out.

I used these command in cpan
 perl -MCPAN -e shell
 force install WWW::Curl::Easy

```
cpan[1]> force install WWW::Curl::Easy
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 16 Feb 2017 05:17:02 GMT
Running install for module 'WWW::Curl::Easy'
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/S/SZ/SZBALINT/WWW-Curl-4.17.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /root/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
Configuring S/SZ/SZBALINT/WWW-Curl-4.17.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Locating required external dependency bin:curl-config... missing.
Unresolvable missing external dependency.
Please install 'curl-config' seperately and try again.
NA: Unable to build distribution on this platform.
No 'Makefile' created  SZBALINT/WWW-Curl-4.17.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 SZBALINT/WWW-Curl-4.17.tar.gz                : writemakefile NO -- No 'Makefile' created
```

Comment: Please install 'curl-config' seperately and try again.

Comment: Look into [this](http://blogs.perl.org/users/samuel_kaufman/2013/12/resolving-non-perl-dependencies-for-perl-modules-in-debianubuntu.html).

Comment: thanks guys but how do I install  'curl-config' ?

Comment: please see the answer posted

Comment: @Ganesh For **ubuntu**:`apt-get install curl-config`, **centOS**:`yum install curl-config`. It depends on the os environment you are using. Try searching how to install packages on the os version you are using!

Comment: Your answer worked on Ubuntu 18.04.  You might consider accepting your answer so that others can benefit from seeing a resolve the works.  I upvoted both your question and answer.

Answer (score 5):

I use this and it's install "WWW::Curl::Easy" Module without any error

**apt-get install libwww-curl-perl**

Answer (score 2):

On Red Hat try:

yum install curl curl-devel

installing only curl didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you the problem

> Locating required external dependency bin:curl-config... missing.
>
> Unresolvable missing external dependency. Please install 'curl-config'
>
> seperately and try again.

So install curl-config and try again. Always check for dependencies.
Installing curl-config methods depends on the OS.

for Redhat for instance it will be

```
yum install curl
```

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD 12.2-RELEASE

**cd /usr/ports/www/p5-WWW-Curl
make install clean**
...
(cleaning for curl-7.80.0
cleaning for p5-WWW-Curl)